# Некорректная работа SQL запроса при выборе количества товаров в категориях и подкатегориях

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Существует 3 таблицы:

1. "goods" - товары.
2. "grup_goods" - хранит информацию о группах товара.
3. "grup_link_goods" - связывает таблицу goods с таблицей grup_goods.

   Задача заключается в том, чтобы вывести категории и количество находящихся в них товаров, делаю так:

   ```
   SELECT
       gr_g.url AS url, 
       gr_g.grup_img AS grup_img, 
       gr_g.name_menu AS name_menu, 
       gr_g.title AS title, 
       IFNULL(COUNT(gr_l_g.id), 0) AS count 
   FROM
       grup_goods AS gr_g  
       LEFT JOIN 
           grup_link_goods AS gr_l_g ON (gr_g.id = gr_l_g.id_grup)  
       WHERE gr_g.id_part=.$id. 
       GROUP BY gr_l_g.id_grup
       ORDER BY gr_g.id ASC
   ```

Всё бы нечего)), но результат немного не тот, который ожидался:
Получается примерно так:

```
name_menu | count (5 шт)
name_menu | count (3 шт)
name_menu | count (0 шт)
```

А нужно:

```
name_menu | count (5 шт)
name_menu | count (3 шт)
name_menu | count (0 шт)
name_menu | count (0 шт)
name_menu | count (0 шт)
```

Выводится только одна категория с количеством товара = 0, а остальные с нулевым количеством куда - то пропадает((.

В чём может быть проблема???

Comment: может нужна группировка по таблице gr_g?

Comment: Нет, это тут вообще не причём, количество выводит верное, пропадают значения = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам @3per верно сказал про групировку, ее требуется делать по полю главной таблицы (gr_g.id), а не таблицы используемой при LEFT JOIN, ведь вы выбираете все данные из основной таблицы, а не из вторичной.

По сути при подобном запросе, который сейчас у вас, вы выбираете набор различных данных из вторичной таблицы (NULL, 1, 2, 3...), а значения основной таблицы, которых нет во вторичной просто отсекаются переходя в NULL.

У вас выводится всего один 0, потому что при присоединении таблицы, поле gr_l_g.id_grup равно NULL и все нулевые значения по сути сгруппированы в эту строку вывода.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, всё верно, всё рабатает